# How to raise an event when a new handler is assigned?

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0

I am trying to copy functionality provided by an existing .NET XNA class's event: [NetworkSession.GamerJoined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.net.networksession.gamerjoined(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx).

When the event is assigned to it can immediately be raised, e.g.:

```
myNetworkSession.GamerJoined += GamerJoinedEventHandler;

void GamerJoinedEventHandler(object sender, GamerJoinedEventArgs e)
{
    // If you put a beakpoint on the assignment line above and another here
    // this handler is called during the assignment.
}
```

How can I achieve this if I am writing my own `NetworkSession` class with the `GamerJoined` event?

Comment: If you have use for a side-effect in your event handler method then just call it directly, you don't need XNA to do it for you.  Fairly likely you'll have to refactor it and move some code into a private method since it ought to be difficult to construct a valid GamerJoinedEventArgs instance.

Comment: @HansPassant I am writing an implementation of the class so user's code written for the XNA one will just work using my one.

Comment: Then it is a code smell.  The fact that *some* client code is interested to know when a gamer joined the network, you don't know what that code looks like, does *not* mean that a gamer actually joined.

Comment: Perhaps but my concern is compatibility - and even MS's samples rely on the behaviour. What it does is raise the event for all gamers who joined prior to a client subscribing to the event, see the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the [`add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(ADD_CSHARPKEYWORD);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) contextual keyword.

When you have the line:

```
public event EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs> GamerJoined;
```

This is syntactic sugar for:

```
public event EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs> GamerJoined
{
    add
    {
        this.gamerJoined += (EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(this.gamerJoined, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        this.gamerJoined -= (EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs>)Delegate.Remove(this.gamerJoined, value);
    }
}
```

Where `gamerJoined` is a private backing field for the event. So you can write you own `add` to call the handler e.g.

```
public event EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs> GamerJoined
{
    add
    {
        this.gamerJoined += (EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(this.gamerJoined, value);
        value(this, new GamerJoinedEventArgs(myGamer));
    }
    remove
    {
        this.gamerJoined -= (EventHandler<GamerJoinedEventArgs>)Delegate.Remove(this.gamerJoined, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I have never used it